# Connect to WCF service with name instead of IP

Tags: c#, wcf

Hey I have made an WCF service and would like to be able to connect to it with an dns I set?
as it is now I have to conncet to the baseaddress via the computers ip.
and the DHCP sometimes gives new ip and then the clients have to know the new ip and so on... you hopefully get it :)

so how can I make it connect via a name instead? and like have localhost in baseaddress

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="metaAndErrors" 
               name="VenatoWCF.WCFService">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/End"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  contract="VenatoWCF.IService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="dendei"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/mex" 
                  binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                  contract="IMetadataExchange">
          <identity>
            <dns value="dendei"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/VenatoWCFconsole/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="metaAndErrors">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

been trying something like this but no luck xD, i would like to connect from client side with "http://dendei:8732/VenatoWCFconsole/"

so even if my ip changes the clients dont have to make changes to connect to me

thank you for answers!

Comment: How are you hosting the WCF?  IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no matter what, something will have to supply the endpoint address (i.e. ip/port).  If that value is set to change frequently, i would set a port forwarder in between your client and service.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding

Comment: yes what worked good for me was the option added in .net 4.0 <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress/> so i can keep localhost and still connect from anywhere, if i have the port forwared.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a scenario that should "just work".  Your service base address in the service config should be able to use localhost as you illustrated.  In your client-side config you should configure your endpoint address using the DNS name for the host where the service is running.

Check that the client machine can ping the service machine using the DNS name.  If that resolves ok, there is no reason why WCF shouldn't connect.  You should not have to change any config when the DHCP server decides to allocate a new IP address, so long as clients can still resolve the DNS name to the new IP address.

For example, in your client config...

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://dendei:8732/VenatoWCFconsole/End"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="sameBindingConfigYouAlreadyUse"
    contract="Whatever.YourContractNameIs" name="YourEndpointName" />
</client>
```

Update: I just spotted there's a problem in your service config above.  In the service endpoint config you should specify address as just the additional part of the URI that will get appended to the base-address.  So, instead of `address="http://localhost:8732/End"`, you just need `address="End"`.

Comment: hmm ok thank you, but is the correct way to try and connect like this "http://dendei:8732/VenatoWCFconsole/"

Comment: agreed, you may need to check the DNS you are trying to connect via is also specifying the correct port number

Comment: im not sure i get it im currently trying to just access the page in my web browser? should i create a client? the client is soap but i have problems with my php atm so cant check with that just now ... xD

Answer (score 0):

As i understood you don't have a static ip address and try to overcame this by having a static DNS name, in my opinion this would not work because you should have a static ip address and than assign to it a static DNS name, then try to connect.

Comment: yes i dont want to have to use the ip when i connect but how do i setup this? :)

Comment: That thing is not something to set up, you should buy a static ip address from your ISP. And then set for that static ip a DNS and use it.